# When I try to add a new Python Interpreter in Eclipse, I get an error involving conda. Why?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to add a new interpreter in Project/Preferences under PyDev.  When I select the executable for my 3.7 interpreter, and I click apply, I get

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program python3.7/bin/conda error=2, No such file or directory
```

Why does it look for conda?  I have never had that happen before when adding a new interpreter

Comment: Try uninstalling PyDev and reinstalling it. Also remove any and all paths to Conda contained within your PATH environment variable

Comment: @ramhound After playing around with it, the add interpreter process still complained, but when I exited it out of it, the 3.7 interpreter was selected and I can use it.  Weird.  I did remove any trace of conda from my path.